# How to Create Scroll Transition?

Tags: reactjs, animation, gsap, scrollmagic

I want to add a transition of this type on a website I creating on React. Can some please guide me on how I can achieve this or is there any lib that I can refer?

[Scroll Transition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMtQu.gif)

Comment: GreenSock doesn't recommend ScrollMagic. Instead they recommend the official scroll plugin: [ScrollTrigger](https://greensock.com/scrolltrigger/)! It's better in every way.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [react-scroll](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scroll) for scrolling and effect